# PHP GD snowflake fractal

Tags: php, gd, fractals

How can you make a [**Koch Snowflake Fractal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) using php gd so that it comes out like this...

---

[image]

[image]

---

Is it possible?  Is there another resource I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageline, imagerotate, imagefill, and imagefilledpolygon are your friends. they're all in the php manual. as far as the math goes, you can add this to your references: http://www.fractaldesign.net/algor.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image and draw lines on it using [imageline](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php).

Another posibility is using SVG. Since SVG are basically XML documents, you can make an SVG image by simply echo'ing some XML.

```
echo '<line x1="'.$startx.'" y1="'.$starty.'" x2="300" y2="300" />';
```